# Changing index format of xts

Tags: r, xts

I have an 'xts' object with the index format of `"%Y-%m-%d"` and want to change the index format to `"%Y-%m"`.

My problem is that `tformat(x) <- "%Y-%m"` only changes the format when I print the time series, but I wan't to change the index itself.

And `format(as.Date(index(x), "%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y-%m")` just simply extracts the index and gives it as a character string.

How can I do it the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index of an xts object is actually stored as a date represented as a number, and this doesn't change however you choose to format it.

For example, let's take the following object:

```r
library(xts)

x <- xts(1:12, seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), by = "month", length.out = 12))

x
#>            [,1]
#> 2020-01-01    1
#> 2020-02-01    2
#> 2020-03-01    3
#> 2020-04-01    4
#> 2020-05-01    5
#> 2020-06-01    6
#> 2020-07-01    7
#> 2020-08-01    8
#> 2020-09-01    9
#> 2020-10-01   10
#> 2020-11-01   11
#> 2020-12-01   12
```

Now we can `unclass` `x` to see that it is "really" an array with some attributes. One of these is the date, `"index"`, stored in numeric format:

```r
unclass(x)
#>       [,1]
#>  [1,]    1
#>  [2,]    2
#>  [3,]    3
#>  [4,]    4
#>  [5,]    5
#>  [6,]    6
#>  [7,]    7
#>  [8,]    8
#>  [9,]    9
#> [10,]   10
#> [11,]   11
#> [12,]   12
#> attr(,"index")
#>  [1] 1577836800 1580515200 1583020800 1585699200 1588291200 1590969600
#>  [7] 1593561600 1596240000 1598918400 1601510400 1604188800 1606780800
#> attr(,"index")attr(,"tzone")
#> [1] "UTC"
#> attr(,"index")attr(,"tclass")
#> [1] "Date"
```

So now let's change the format:

```
tformat(x) <- "%Y-%m"

x
#>         [,1]
#> 2020-01    1
#> 2020-02    2
#> 2020-03    3
#> 2020-04    4
#> 2020-05    5
#> 2020-06    6
#> 2020-07    7
#> 2020-08    8
#> 2020-09    9
#> 2020-10   10
#> 2020-11   11
#> 2020-12   12
```

When we `unclass` again, we see that the `"index"` attribute is unchanged, though the formatting has changed:

```
unclass(x)
#>       [,1]
#>  [1,]    1
#>  [2,]    2
#>  [3,]    3
#>  [4,]    4
#>  [5,]    5
#>  [6,]    6
#>  [7,]    7
#>  [8,]    8
#>  [9,]    9
#> [10,]   10
#> [11,]   11
#> [12,]   12
#> attr(,"index")
#>  [1] 1577836800 1580515200 1583020800 1585699200 1588291200 1590969600
#>  [7] 1593561600 1596240000 1598918400 1601510400 1604188800 1606780800
#> attr(,"index")attr(,"tzone")
#> [1] "UTC"
#> attr(,"index")attr(,"tclass")
#> [1] "Date"
#> attr(,"index")attr(,"tformat")
#> [1] "%Y-%m"
```

So when you say you want to change the index itself, it's not clear what you mean. The index has to be internally represented as *some* exact date-time, however it is printed. There really is no problem in just changing the printed format the way you have done.

Comment: well, the problem is i have another df with monthly data and I want to merge the two, but one hast the first of each month as index and the other one has the day of the first observation as index.. so they don't match up exactly

Comment: @ITsMe so it sounds like what you are trying to do is round the dates so they match. You need to change the actual date recorded if you want them to match up - you can't just ask xts to make the indexing a bit fuzzy. The easiest way to do this is to use `lubridate::floor_date(df$date, "month")` on the data frame with the day of the first observation as index. This will drop the observations to the first of the month on which they were made. When you format it, just drop the day from the date format so that it is obvious you are comparing months rather than days.

Comment: thank you. that works for me,
even though it's kinda annoying to me that its so complicated to manipulate the index of an xts itself